# Shopify app extension fetch data with my database

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-storefront-api, shopify-liquid

I was wondering how to get the data from my database(mySQL || mongodb) and then use App Block it displaying it.

Can someone please help.

Comment: find a solution to this?